# In Drupal, how do I override a template in a core module without modifying the actual core?

Tags: drupal

I want to edit the search results of a search using the search module. The template in question is `search-result.tpl.php`. I see that it's in `html/modules/search`, but I'd like to  keep the modification out of the core and keep it in my `sites` folder. Is there a way to change the place that drupal looks for that specific template? If not, how can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the `search-result.tpl.php` into your theme's directory, modify it as needed, and [clear the theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176).

You may also want to check out the [About overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/173880) handbook page for additional details.